# How do you set the number of words in the visual dictionary?

Tags: classification

How do you set the number of words in the visual dictionary?

I tried to understand the different steps to obtain the visual dictionary first:

Feature detection:

1. Examines every pixel to see if there is a feature present at that pixel.

Feature description:

2. Each image is abstracted by several local patches
3. Feature representation methods deal with how to represent the patches as numerical vectors.

Codebook generation:

4. Convert vector-represented patches to "codewords"
5. Codewords are then defined as the centers of the learned clusters
   by using K means and/or the Euclidean distance will be computed.

I am assuming that the Bag of Words is used for image classification, but I don't really understand how you set the number of words in the visual dictionary. I would really appreciate the help or please correct me if I was wrong in the steps of obtaining the visual dictionary!

Comment: Using cross-validation, maybe?